# sort list of strings -an inner list in an outer list

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am trying to solve the following:
write a function :

```
def sort_anagrams(list_of_strings):
```

This function should receive a list of words and get back anagrams, meaning all words with the same letters will be presented in an inner list and all inner list in an outer list, see example

```
list_of_words = ['deltas', 'retainers', 'desalt', 'pants', 'slated', 'generating', 'ternaries', 'smelters', 'termless', 'salted', 'staled', 'greatening', 'lasted', 'resmelts']
```

The output should be:

```
[
  ['deltas', 'desalt', 'slated', 'salted', 'staled', 'lasted'],
  ['retainers', 'ternaries'], ['pants'], ['generating', 'greatening'], 
  ['smelters', 'termless', 'resmelts']
]
```

I  tried the following :

```
list_of_words=['deltas', 'retainers', 'desalt', 'pants', 'slated', 'generating', 'ternaries', 'smelters', 'termless', 'salted', 'staled', 'greatening', 'lasted', 'resmelts'] 

cx=sorted(list_of_words,reverse=False,key=lambda x:sorted(x))  
print(cx)
```

But this just puts anagrams next to each other without the inner lists that I want:

```
['deltas', 'desalt', 'slated', 'salted', 'staled', 'lasted', 'generating', 'greatening', 'retainers', 'ternaries', 'pants', 'smelters', 'termless', 'resmelts']
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one approach using `collections.defaultdict`.

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

list_of_words = ['deltas', 'retainers', 'desalt', 'pants', 'slated', 'generating', 'ternaries', 'smelters', 'termless', 'salted', 'staled', 'greatening', 'lasted', 'resmelts'] 
result = defaultdict(list)
for item in list_of_words:
    result["".join(sorted(item))].append(item)
```

---

Using `setdefault`

**Ex:**

```
result = {}
for item in list_of_words:
    result.setdefault("".join(sorted(item)), []).append(item)

print(list(result.values()))
```

**Output:**

```
[['deltas', 'desalt', 'slated', 'salted', 'staled', 'lasted'],
 ['retainers', 'ternaries'],
 ['pants'],
 ['generating', 'greatening'],
 ['smelters', 'termless', 'resmelts']]
```

Comment: thank you all  this is very helpful , since this is a basic course , is it possible to do it  without the importing ,rather use a simpler way ?

Comment: @zachi. You do not need to import anything for the `setdefault` method

Answer (score 2):

First sort the list_of_words using sorted as the key, just in the same way you have done. Then use `itertools.groupby` to group them based on `set`

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [list(grp) for _,grp in groupby(sorted(list_of_words, key=sorted), set)]
[['deltas', 'desalt', 'slated', 'salted', 'staled', 'lasted'], ['generating', 'greatening'], ['retainers', 'ternaries'], ['pants'], ['smelters', 'termless', 'resmelts']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the use of the [permutations](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) function will help.

```py
from itertools import permutations
anagrams = []
for one_word in list_of_words:
    temp_list = [''.join(word) for word in permutations(one_word)]
    anagrams.append(temp_list)

print(anagrams)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort your list and then use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group all items that have the same characters in them.

For that, you would first normalize each word so that you can find items that belong to another. For this, you can simply sort the characters in the string. Then, you have to sort the list of words by that normalized value and afterwards group them by that. And then you have to unpack everything to get the desired output:

```
from itertools import groupby

result = [
     [y[1] for y in items]
     for _, items in groupby(
         sorted(
             [(''.join(sorted(w)), w) for w in list_of_words]
         ), key=lambda x: x[0])
]

# [['deltas', 'desalt', 'lasted', 'salted', 'slated', 'staled'],
#  ['generating', 'greatening'],
#  ['retainers', 'ternaries'],
#  ['pants'],
#  ['resmelts', 'smelters', 'termless']]
```

By normalizing the words each first this avoids having to sort each word multiple times.